# How to clear IAP transaction history from real AppleID?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm building an app with In-App-Purchase feature. I just implemented it and made a sandbox purchase using my real device with my real AppleID.

I want to know if it is possible to clear this transaction as it wasn't made by a test account, but by a real one.

Comment: If it is a non-consumable purchase then that Apple ID owns it forever in the sandbox. You can't remove it